# Error - org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossLocalXAException: Trying to start a new tx when old is not complete

Tags: java, sql, jboss

Our Java Application is running on RHEL 8.5 OS. And we are using the JBoss version of 4.2.1 GA. Our application worked fine for a few months. Recently, we encountered the below problem repeatedly which occupied almost 5 GB in the jboss.log file and we are trying to find the root cause.

```
WARN  [JDBCSupport] SQLException caught, SQLState null code:0- assuming deadlock detected, try:18
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 6a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7c1fff status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 6a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7c1fff status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >))
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:94)
        at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport$JDBCTxRunner.execute(JDBCSupport.java:383)
        at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport$JDBCTxRunner.executeWithRetry(JDBCSupport.java:407)
        at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager.reapUnreferencedMessages(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:2357)
        at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager.access$1000(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:78)
        at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager$Reaper.run(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:2381)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 6a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7c1fff status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManager.java:343)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.reconnectManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:518)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:399)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:842)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:88)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 6a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7c1fff status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener$TransactionSynchronization.checkEnlisted(TxConnectionManager.java:744)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener.enlist(TxConnectionManager.java:577)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManager.java:337)
        ... 11 more
05:51:09,339 WARN  [JDBCSupport] Trying again after a pause
05:51:09,531 WARN  [loggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.enliststarterror] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.enliststarterror] TransactionImple.enlistResource - XAResource.start returned: XAException.XAER_PROTO for < 131075, 31, 29, 1-6a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7c20036a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7c2006^
 ERROR [STDERR] org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossLocalXAException: Trying to start a new tx when old is not complete! old: < 131075, 31, 29, 1-6a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7bf8476a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7bf84a^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ >, new < 131075, 31, 29, 1-6a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7c20036a288574:63f3:63d001d8:7c2006^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ >, flags 0
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$LocalXAResource.start(TxConnectionManager.java:886)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:774)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:497)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionManager.java:773)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener.enlist(TxConnectionManager.java:564)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManager.java:337)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.reconnectManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:518)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:399)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:842)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:88)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport$JDBCTxRunner.execute(JDBCSupport.java:383)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport$JDBCTxRunner.executeWithRetry(JDBCSupport.java:407)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager.reapUnreferencedMessages(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:2357)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager.access$1000(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:78)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager$Reaper.run(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:2381)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
05:51:09,531 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)




 ERROR [JDBCSupport] Retried 25 times, now giving up
05:51:06,096 ERROR [JDBCPersistenceManager] Failed to reap
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to excecute transaction
        at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport$JDBCTxRunner.executeWithRetry(JDBCSupport.java:423)
        at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager.reapUnreferencedMessages(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:2357)
        at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager.access$1000(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:78)
        at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager$Reaper.run(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:2381)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Please let us clear the below questions,

1. Why this error occured repeatedly?
2. In which condition, the above error occurs?
3. How to prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled by your question.  Your issue is happening with JBoss Messaging, but JBoss Messaging was not included in JBoss 4.2.1 GA.

In any event, your JBoss Messaging (JMS service) is not functioning.  Most likely, it is completely offline.  I would recommend clearing out all of the JBoss Messaging tables from the database and starting with a clean database.

In your servers `deploy/messaging` directory, there should be a `*-persistence-service.xml` file.  This configures the database storage.  If the `CreateTablesOnStartup` are set to `true`, then JBoss Messaging will create the tables automatically.  Maybe just rename the existing tables, or take backups if you like.

The `*-persistence-service.xml` file will have the connection details for the database, the tables will be named `JBM`.

Comment: I went back and looked...  There are instructions on jboss.org for installing JBoss Messging on Jboss 4.2.